# How negative indexes work in lodash's _.includes?

Tags: javascript, lodash

Negative numbers in _includes doesn't work as expected.

```
console.log(_.includes(['a','b','c'],'b', -1)); //false
```

```
console.log(_.includes(['a','b','c'],'b', -2)); //true
```

```
console.log(_.includes(['a','b','c'],'b', -3)); //true
```

```
console.log(_.includes(['a','b','c'],'b', -4)); //true
```

... and etc "true"

In case of "-3", "-4" indexes I expect False-s in output, not True

What do I miss?

Comment: Have you checked [the documentation](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#includes)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`negative`** index is like

```
array[array.length - index]
```

In array `['a','b','c']`,  `-1` would be `'c'`

```
array[3 - 1]  =  array[2] = 'c'
//    ^ length of `['a','b','c']`
```

**In `_.includes(['a','b','c'],'b', -3)`**

```
array[3 - 3] = array[0]
//    ^ length of `['a','b','c']`
```

It starts searching for `'b'` from index `0` to index `3`

Comment: So, is it correct, what in case of "0", it search for whole array, not only first index ('a' value)?

Comment: @AeffRara yes, because it's a `fromIndex` where the searching starts from

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#includes) says the following:

> ```
> _.includes(collection, value, [fromIndex=0])
> ```
>
> Checks if `value` is in `collection`. If `collection` is a string, it's
>   checked for a substring of `value`, otherwise [`SameValueZero`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-samevaluezero) is 
>   used for equality comparisons. **If `fromIndex` is negative, it's used
>   as the offset from the end of `collection`.**
>
> **Since**
>
> 0.1.0
>
> **Arguments**
>
> - `collection (Array|Object|string)`: The collection to inspect.
> - `value (*)`: The value to search for.
> - `[fromIndex=0] (number)`: The index to search from.
>
> **Returns**
>
> `(boolean)`: Returns true if value is found, else false.

**@EDIT**

**Examples**

```
_.includes(['a','b','c','d'],'b', -3); //=> true
```

Starts from `'b'` and because `'b'` is included in the subarray you get `true`.

```
_.includes(['a','b','c','d'],'b', -2) //=> false
```

Starts from `'c'` and because `'b'` is not included in the subarray you get `false`.

Comment: I understand about end of collection, but in that case indexes in this array should be [-3, -2, -1], so when _.includes(['a','b','c'],'b', -3), it should show False, because 'a' != 'b'

Comment: @AeffRara with `_.includes(['a','b','c'],'b', -3)` you start from `'a'` which includes the whole array. And since `'b'` is included in the rest of the array starting from index `-3` (remember, the whole array) you get `true`.